# Is it possible to use lint to find unnecessary lines of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, jslint, jshint, rollupjs

As you'll see from the example below, I have some Javascript. There's a redundant line that sets foo to 3 that could be removed. Is there any automated / command line tools that can find this line and flag it as a potential code error?

I've tried JSHint and JSLint, both report this code as ok.

I've also tried YUI compressor and Google Closure Compiler, but they just produce minified code (I've known them to throw errors with dodgy JS, so it was a long shot).

I've seen tools in Java that can find these pointless assignments, so I'm hopeful that something may exist for Javascript.

Example:

```
var foo = 1;

function oi() {
    'use strict';
    foo = 3;
    foo = 2;
    return 5;
}


console.log("foo = " + foo);
console.log("oi retval = " + oi());
console.log("foo = " + foo);
```

Console logging included to make sure nothing optimises out the var and the function.

Comment: The definition of "unnecessary" is always a bit fuzzy. What if you have a setter that gets called when you assign a value? The check would be quite complicated (because you can also remove a setter, not just have it).

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars, https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions or https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare might catch similar mistakes

Comment: In this case, it's identifying setting the variable again, when there's no way that foo=3 could be used (discounting multiple threads). I'm looking for a way to be warned that I reset foo to 2 when I meant for it to be 3. In Javascript, would use of setters eliminate this? I would have thought it would make it harder to statically analyse.

Comment: eslint - good shout. Sadly, it behaves the same as jslint / jshint and ignores the reassignment. If the code was using `var foo = ...` twice, it would have caught it.

Comment: I just tried TreeShaking with Rollup, with the same results (not too surprising because it does run that line of code, even if it has no effect). I'm beginning to think that something possible is Java is not so in JavaScript.

Comment: I've also tried SonarQube, but I may have missed an option to enable a check. I know this can find similar code in Java